# Getting LTE Data balance using adb command to get output in terminal

Tags: android, sdk, adb

Is there any way i can get the data balance of the LTE data balance using adb command.

i have something like below

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:*100*1%23
```

here im using call command and giving **USSD** code but this works on the phone side which pops out the ussd window with the balance but not on the adb shell terminal.

Is there any way to find out the data balance on the terminal end using USSD code but not on the Smartphone Screen. Or by any other way to grep the data balance from phone screen.

Does anyone could help me?

Thanks